# Commands Not Executing When Using At Command

Tags: bash, at-utility

I have a very simple bash script written,

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "python /home/user1/Downloads/program.py" | at 10:00
```

but it doesn't execute. All of the jobs seem unexecuted because when I run atq (at queue) I see all the attempts I have made.

I am on Linux Mint if that helps at all.

Comment: What happens when you run just `at 10:00` *in command line*?

Comment: Is `atd` running?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can go about troubleshooting to find the root cause of your problem.
Create a simple python script at `/home/user1/Downloads/date.py`

`date.py` contains the following entries.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import datetime
print ("From date.py: It is now", datetime.datetime.now() )
```

Then schedule the script to run and write any output to `/home/user1/date.log`
For example,

```
echo "/home/user1/Downloads/date.py >> /home/user1/date.log 2>&1" | at 12:15
```

Check `/home/user1/date.log` and you should see an entry like this after the job runs:

```
From date.py: It is now 2020-07-05 12:15:00.637742
```